# GRUB boot ThinkPad X230 BIOS image?

Tags: grub2, thinkpad, firmware

I followed the advice on the "[Think Wiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/)" ("[on Debian and Ubuntu](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/BIOS_Upgrade#On_Debian_and_Ubuntu)"):

```
sudo apt-get install grub-imageboot
sudo mkdir -p /boot/images
sudo cp /home/youruser/Downloads/6uuj12uc.iso /boot/images
sudo update-grub
```

[image: graphics distortion]

However, for me, when I select that option from GRUB, I get what looks like graphics memory distortion, then it scrolls down half a page and dies.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to get it to boot up with `grub-imageboot`, neither with the .iso or the .img which grub-imageboot detected and installed entries for resulted in anything but a corrupted video display.

I put the iso on a bootable usb with `dd` and it worked fined.